# Rollups vs Plasma

Tags: rollups, plasma

This question is related to my another question - [Plasma - "If owner does not care about their asset, then an "invalid" outcome may result"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/146977/plasma-if-owner-does-not-care-about-their-asset-then-an-invalid-outcome-ma)

Here https://vitalik.ca/general/2021/01/05/rollup.html Vitalik says that Rollups are better than Plasma:

1. In terms of security - because data is on L1, dispute resolution is on L1 (fraud proofs are on chain) and "internal EVM" is also on L1.
2. It is more "general" than Plasma.

And I can not get the second point. How putting data on chain makes Rollup work with smart contracts, but Plasma works only for token (assets) transactions?